# How to switch the state of buttons in react hooks after updating it through rest api?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, react-router

Hey guys I am very new to react and trying to make the frontend of a blog web application. I am able to show the posts on the homepage and I am able to make the like button work without API calls, just with managing states.

Now with API call, the like button shows red(button fills with red) if the post is liked by the user and I am able to unlike it by clicking it, it changes the count and it unlike the post in the backend, but it doesn't change the button state to unlike button and it keeps on unliking it rather than switching to like button state.

If the post is not liked by the user, then the button completely disappears and doesn't show on the screen, so I am not able to like the post.

This is the code I have written, It is not a good way to write react code I think, If anyone can help resolve this issue, it would be highly enlightening as I am still learning. Please do ask for more information if needed.

This is the code.

```
const [liked, setLiked] = useState(null) 

    function setlikeCount(post){
        return(
            post.like_count = post.like_count + 1
        )
    }

    function setunlikeCount(post){
        return(
            post.like_count = post.like_count - 1
        )
    }

    function likePosts(post) {
        console.log('liked the post')
        return(
            axiosInstance.post('api/posts/' + post.slug + '/like/')
        )
    }   

    function unlikePosts(post) {
        console.log('unliked the post')
        return(
            axiosInstance.delete('api/posts/' + post.slug + '/like/')
        )
    }

{myposts.posts && myposts.posts.results.map((post) => {
    return (
        <h4>{post.title}</h4>
    )
}


{post.likes && post.likes.map((lik, index) => {
    console.log(user, lik.id)
    return (
    user === lik.id ? (<FavoriteRoundedIcon style={{ color: "red" }}
                key={index}
                onClick={ () =>{
                    unlikePosts(post)
                    setunlikeCount(post)
                    setLiked((liked) => liked===false)
                }} 
              />)
            :   (<FavoriteBorderRoundedIcon key={index}
                    onClick={ () =>{
                    likePosts(post)
                    setlikeCount(post)
                    setLiked((liked)=> liked===true)
                    }}
                />)
    )
    })
}

const [myposts, setPosts] = useState({
    posts: null,
})
```

fetching posts

```
useEffect(() => {
        axiosInstance.get('api/posts/myhome').then((res) => {
        const allPosts = res.data;
        setLoading(false)
        setError("")
        setPosts({ posts: allPosts })
        // console.log(allPosts.results['0'].likes['0']);
        
    })
    .catch(() => {
        setLoading(false)
        setPosts({})
        setError('Something went wrong!')
    })

    }, [setPosts])
```

In the code, the `user` has the user's `id`.
Is it possible to check the condition like `user in lik.id` than `user === lik.id`, like how we check conditions in python?

`lik` looks like this `[{id: 1, username: "testuser12"}]`

Thanks

Comment: if add code in [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/) for debugging is better and great.

Comment: you used `user === lik.id` insetad of `user.id === lik.id`. it can be the reason.

Comment: No, actually user contains user's id.
Is it possible to check like `if user in lik.id` using the word `in` like in python?

Comment: lik.id in an array and you want to check whether user exists in the array ?

Comment: yes, it has. you can use js feature similar to that. you can use `find` or if/in statement like `if (1 in [1,2,3] === true) {
}`

Comment: more like if ("id" in link){}... you can check if it is contain given key in object

Comment: lik shows `Array(0)` when no user's have liked the post and shows a list object if someone likes the post `id: 1
username: "testuser12"`

Comment: if lik.id is array name it lik.ids ... and then just ::: lik.ids.includes(user.id)

Comment: If i check like this `user in lik.id` then I get an error like this `TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for '1' in 1`

Comment: you can use lik.id.includes(user) if lik.id is an array

Comment: lik.id is not an array, it is an element of the array lik.
`[{id: 1, username: "testuser12"}]` This is how lik looks like

Comment: you mean post.likes is the array if the user exist and show the button based on that ?

Comment: post.likes is an array with user id and username, so I want to show the button filled with red if the user has already liked the post and an empty button if he hasn't. so far, if he has liked the post, the button is showing red, but if I click it, it unlikes the post, but not changing back to the other button instead keeps on unliking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to show the button based on the content of the array like below

```
{post.likes && post.likes.find(x=>x.id===user) ? 
    (<FavoriteRoundedIcon style={{ color: "red" }}
            key={index}
            onClick={ () =>{
                unlikePosts(post)
                setunlikeCount(post)
                setLiked((liked) => liked===false)
            }} 
          />)
        :   (<FavoriteBorderRoundedIcon key={index}
                onClick={ () =>{
                likePosts(post)
                setlikeCount(post)
                setLiked((liked)=> liked===true)
                }}
            />)
}
```

If the array has values and the user is part of the array you show red button and if the array is not defined or user is not in the array you show the other button.

Comment: Tried this, now the buttons are showing , but I am able to only unlike posts and not like. everytime I click, its unliking the post the counter is decreasing and the button doesn't change state

Comment: thats because you are not updating the post.likes, you will have to update that when liking and unliking, if its in the state you will have to update the state

Comment: Oh..okay! so how can I update post.likes? I have only id and username in it. Can you give me a hint or a source to similar solution? I'm sorry as i am a complete newbie to this.

Comment: is posts in the state ?

Comment: I have updated the question with posts. please do have a look at it.

Comment: is this a screen that shows a single screen ? or a listing screen ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/223545/discussion-between-guruparan-giritharan-and-danny).

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, your setLiked method isn't right. if you want to set it to true/false just call:

```
setLiked(true)
```

Secondary, you should init your liked state. Meaning you need to useEffect (when the component loads) and read from your API if post liked or not. But the initial value better to be false and not null.

Comment: I tried with setLiked(false), but it still has the same issue.